# view controller initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c

Usually a view controller is initialized in the Application Delegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    TestViewController *VC = [[TestViewController alloc] **init**];
    self.window.rootViewController = VC;
    return YES;
}
```

But `VC` will implement an initialization method like `- (instancetype)initWithNibName:`.

How does `init` call `initWithNibName:`? What is the call sequence?

Comment: `init` doesn't call `initWithNibName:`

Comment: So, All the viewControllers should implement "init" method and inside "init" method need to invoke "initWithNibName" ?

Comment: depends. if you are not using nibs, you don't need to call `initWithNibName`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default implementation, it simply calls the superclass's version:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Implementing `initWithNibName` is not required, since the default init method will call the super implementation of `initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil` for you.

If you are creating your `TestViewController` using code only (no xibs), then the code you posted is acceptable. Otherwise, you should call `initWithNibName` and pass the name of the nib to be used for that view controller.